# How do I go about plotting hyperbolic functions (sinh,cosh,tanh) into the same graph/figure in matlab using for loops?

Tags: matlab, function, loops, plot, figure

This is what I have for my code so far however the graph does not come out at all.

```
`clear;
clc;
close all;

for a = -2:1:2;
    y = -1:.1:1;
    cosh(a);
    sinh(a);
    tanh(a);
end

plot(a,sinh(a),a,cosh(a),a,tanh(a));`
```

Answer (score 4):

Several issues:

1. When you run `cosh(a);` in your for loop, you are not saving the value.
2. There's no need for the loop anyway since `cosh` etc. take vector inputs
3. `y` is unused.
4. As far as the plotting goes, you can plot multiple x,y series like that, but after the loop, `a` is just a scalar, so this won't plot anything useful.

Just do: `a = -2:2; plot(a,sinh(a),a,cosh(a),a,tanh(a));`